# How can I test if my iterations are running infinitely?

Tags: r, while-loop, iteration

Good evening,

I wanted to do an iteration using R with the following code:

```
a<- 2
f <- function(x){
  x <-1
  f <- a*x
  x <- f
}  #function is hereby defined

# iterations
while (x<3){
  f
}
```

The function f should start out with the value x = 1. then a*x becomes f and f is the new value for x. This whole loop shall run as long as x < 3, however I get stuck in an infinite loop because I just cannot figure out how to assign variables in iterations...could somebody maybe help me?

Kind regards and thanks in advance for every comment!

Comment: It is not clear when you are defining a function name as `f` and then inside the function assign `f` from `a*x`

Comment: There are a number of problems here. You're defining a function `f` that takes input `x`, but you then always set `x <- 1`, so the input never matters; the outcome is always the same. Your `while` loop is checking whether `x < 3`, but `x` is never defined in the global environment (you only define it in the function scope, which is not the same), so the `while` loop shouldn't even start (try `rm(x)` and rerun the while statement). Inside the `while` loop, you only stated `f`, not `f()`, so the loop just prints the contents of `f` (it doesn't run it). It may be best to learn more R first.